# Two toggle and two click on the same function with different behavior for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle

i try to create a event with java-script that will allowed me to toggle between the different card and hide and show. 
there is a four card, when you click to the first card it show the information that is below the card and when you click again it hide it, the same thing for the four card,
but i want also that when you click to the second or the third card in case that the first card is open, it close automatically the first to show the second.
Again a toggle event between the four card.

i try to use click two more time, but it seem like i create a conflict between the two.

how can i do to solve this problem.

this is the code that i use:

```js
    $("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
      var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
      $("article").hide();
      $(selector).show();
    });
```

```css
    article:not(#article1) {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article1">cart1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article2">cart 2</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article3">cart 3</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article4">cart 4</a>
    
<article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
<article id="article2">sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
<article id="article3">consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
<article id="article4">adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
```

Comment: I dropped your code into a codepen but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, because it seems to be working for me?  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEZqEv?editors=1010 clicking between the options shows the associated article, can you explain exactly what you're expecting to see and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: when i click between the card it show article it's working but in the same way i want also that if the card 3 is open i want that when i click on it it hide or show

Comment: i add this function below to get the two event but i have two click now and only the first function is running

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little modified method to do your toggling functionality, please add a parent to all the `article` elements and set to `display:none`, when you want to show it, append the class `active`.

Let me know if this fixes your issue!

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var toggleThis = $('article' + $(this).attr('data-toggle') + '')
  if (toggleThis.hasClass('active')) {
    toggleThis.toggleClass('active');
  } else {
    $("article.active").removeClass('active');
    toggleThis.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper article {
  display: none;
}

article.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article1">cart1</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article2">cart 2</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article3">cart 3</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#article4">cart 4</a>
<div class="wrapper">
  <article id="article1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
  <article id="article2" class="active">sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
  <article id="article3">consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
  <article id="article4">adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</article>
</div>
```

Comment: that is working bro, but when you click for the second time on the same card i want to hide it or show

Comment: @NelhAmstrong Can you check it now?

Answer (score 0):

This should hide the article on click without breaking the other functionality:

```
$("article").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```